# How can I make a method that takes more than one Enum type instead of me having to Cast all the time

Tags: c#

I have these method calls and more and this method:

```
    App.DB.UpdateSetting("TimeInterval", (int)Time.UserInput );
    App.DB.UpdateSetting("ThemeColor", (int)Theme.Light );

    public void UpdateSetting(string setting, int value, string text="" )
    {
        lock (locker)
        {
            db2.Execute("UPDATE Setting SET Value = ?, Text = ?" +
                          " WHERE SettingType = ?", value, text, setting);
        }
    }
```

What I would like to do is to be able to avoid typing all those settings to (int). Is there some way I could do that?

Comment: Change `int value` to `Enum value`?

Comment: You could write a T4 template that could auto-generate proxies or at least an overload

Comment: @DavidG that will work of course, but he have to add a Convert.ToInt32 inside the UpdateSettings otherwise he will end writing the result of ToString()

Comment: @Steve Indeed, but it's now a single conversion rather than many :)

Comment: @DavidG  can you explain more.  When I change to Enum value it gives a syntax error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Enum` instead of `int`. That allows you to pass any enum value you ike. The only change you need to make then is to convert the enum to an int inside your method:

```
public void UpdateSetting(string setting, Enum value, string text = "")
{
    var intValue = Convert.ToInt32(value);

    lock (locker)
    {
        db2.Execute("UPDATE Setting SET Value = ?, Text = ?" +
                      " WHERE SettingType = ?", intValue, text, setting);
    }
}
```

Now you can call it like this:

```
App.DB.UpdateSetting("TimeInterval", Time.UserInput );
App.DB.UpdateSetting("ThemeColor", Theme.Light );
```